Do something different on last row of a tuple
I'm manually constructing a JSON so I want the last element to not have a , seperator before the ].
This my code and the documentation says len() works for tuples but I can't get it to work.
The data is a tuple constructed from a SQLite.fetchall() and it has been validated.
for row in data: 
    f.write("{\n")
    f.write(f"'PUT':'{row[1]}'\n")
    if row == len(data):  # I also tried len(data)-1 as suggested by posts
        f.write("}\n")
    else:
        f.write("},\n")

This code constructs the JSON but all elements including the last have the , separator.
What is the best pythonic way to do this?

Give an example of what data looks like and the expected output. Also, it may be better to build a dictionary then use json.dump() to write the JSON structure

I think you want to use the row number. You can use for row_num,row in enumerate(data):

row is not a number, why would it be equal to len()?

By the way any reaon why you are not using json.dump() instead of building the json yourself?

I don't believe single quotes are valid json. You should use double quotes.

The whole loop can be one line: json.dump([{'PUT': row[0]} for row in data], f, indent=2)

Use a str.join to help you format the records, that will get all except the last one, and you can concatenate on the \n to the last record:
# concatenate the last `\n` onto the end after joining
records = ',\n'.join(
    "{\n'PUT':'{value}'\n}".format(value=row[1])
    for row in data
) + '\n'

with open(file) as fh:
    fh.write(records)

Edit
Since it looks like you are trying to roll your own in terms of json encoding, don't. You can make this easier by doing:
import json

records = ',\n'.join(
    (json.dumps({"PUT": row[1]}, indent=0), for row in data)
) + '\n'

Where the indent=0 kwarg will insert the newlines you want:
# compare the two
json.dumps({"some": "value"}, indent=0)
'{\n"some": "value"\n}'

json.dumps({"some": "value"})
'{"some": "value"}'


Solved it
if row == data[len(data)-1]:
    f.write("}\n")
else:
    f.write("},\n")


And what will happen if some row is identical to the last row?
